# magento 2 how to override \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment.php

Tags: magento2

I want to override \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment.php. Guys please help me.

Comment: Any help on this please

Answer (score 0):

Create di.xml in etc folder...and paste below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Payment" />
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the same way u mentioned.But is throwing below error.[Exception]
  Warning: Declaration of Vendor\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::setCreditmemo(Vendor\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo $creditmemo) should be compatible with Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::setCreditmemo(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo $
  creditmemo) in /var/www/html/vendor/app/code/Vendor/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php on line 2551

Comment: <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Vendor\Sales\Model\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

Comment: use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Info;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoManagementInterface as CreditmemoManager;


class Payment extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment

Comment: Vendor\Sales\Model\Order\Payment::setCreditmemo(Vendor\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo $creditmemo) This function's return type and arugument must be same..

Comment: I have just copy pasted vendor file to my theme and updated namespace thats it. Have not changes any functions

Comment: Follow this [blog]https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-block-model-controller-magento-2/

Comment: No' I'm getting issues.